# How to run one browser per thread in Selenium?

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium

I don't think this is particular to Selenium, but I've included that tag because I think it's a problem that's very relevant to Selenium tests.

I have a Browser class that's working as it stands:

```
 public static class Browser {
    private static IWebDriver webDriver;
    private static IWebDriver ieDriver;
    private static IWebDriver chromeDriver;

    private static BrowserType _browserType;

    public static BrowserType BrowserType {
        set {
            _browserType = value;

            switch (_browserType) {
                case BrowserType.IE:
                    if (ieDriver == null)
                    {
                        var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                        ieOptions.InitialBrowserUrl = "about:home";
                        ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(DriverPath, ieOptions);
                    }
                    webDriver = ieDriver;
                    break;
                case BrowserType.Chrome:
                    if (chromeDriver == null)
                    {
                        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPath);
                    }
                    webDriver = chromeDriver;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (chromeDriver == null)
                    {
                        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPath);
                    }
                    webDriver = chromeDriver;
                    break;
                    break;
            }

        } get { return _browserType; }

    }

    public static void Goto(string url) {
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
}
```

The problem is that each of these browsers *should* run in their own thread, so that each test can run on each browser simultaneously (cutting cross-browser test times to the time it takes to run a single browser's test).  Right now tests are called sequentially with the following method:

```
public void RunTest(Func<TestSettings, TestRole, bool> testToRun)
        {
     foreach (var browserType in BrowserTypes)
            {
                  // Assert test passes in given browser
                  // browser should have its own thread
            }
        }
```

How can multithreading be achieved in this scenario?

Comment: what language is this? java or c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreadding is usually achieved to run multiple tests with a testunit.

For PHP you have PHPUnit and some other options:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/parallel-testing-for-phpunit-with-paratest/

For Java you could try to dig in maven-surefire-plugin using JUnit. 
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

Don't know if it is achievable through any selenium API.
If you find a way, please make sure to let me know!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have only one driver:

```
private static IWebDriver webDriver;
```

When you set BrowserType for the first time (for example as IE) you assign webDriver (as IE).
Then when you set BrowserType for the second time (for example as Chrome) you re-assign webDriver (now it is Chrome, IE is lost). You will never get simultaneously run of both browsers in this way.

BrowserType should be set externally. For example, as a parameter of your test-project or from App.config. If you want to run tests in one machine simultaneously, create an app (console app for example), that launches your test-project with different BrowserType values in two different threads.